# jQuery variable class with const index

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I got this code in JavaScript:

```
var document = window.frames[1].document;
var timer = document.getElementsByClassName("timer")[1].innerHTML;
```

and I have the same in jQuery, but it doesn't work

```
var timer = $(".timer", window.parent.frames[1].document).html();
```

Also I don't know how to interpret next to `.timer`  an index like in JavaScript. I mean in JS I got [1] but I don't know where in jQuery to put this.

Sorry for bad english. And thanks for help.

Comment: @edit this code in jQuery return value of .timer with index 0 and i want to return .timer with index 1.

Comment: Ad. Javascript code: Showing the HTML that ```window.frames[1].document;``` refers to would be nice. Ad. jQuery: ".timer" refers to a CSS Class -- from where do you get this? Looks like you are trying to refer to the var timer, but this is not the way to do it.

Comment: Please do some research on `:eq() Selector` in `jquery`. you can find some info at [this link](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)